# How to change name of Payment Module that shows up in VirtoCommerce storefront

Tags: virtocommerce

Trying to change the name of the payment module that shows up in the storefront UI: "Authorize.Net payment gateway" - We would like it to simply say "Use credit card."

I have changed the module.manifest file, and I have changed the "Name" in the authorizeNetPaymentMethodFactory.  The new module is properly installed but the end user UI does not change.  Please provide step-by-step insight on how to change the string that shows up when a user is selecting payment method on checkout, or post-order payment screen.

We have installed the new module.  Done restarts of both the admin appPool and the storeFront AppPool.  We've done uninstalls, restart, upload new module to modules directory, new module shows up, new version #, etc. but end user text never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to override display name, use Storefront Resource File and paymentMethod.code as part of the key.

For example
'checkout.payment_method.AuthorizeNet.display_name' : 'Use credit card'.

And slightly change the code when you display Payment method name
https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-theme-default/blob/521f9e073301f63bab368e16f913a51a40d194ff/assets/js/common-components/paymentMethods.tpl.liquid#L11

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. I overrode the existing binding and went direct to the resources file:

<div class="name">{{ 'checkout.payment_method.AuthorizeNet.display_name' | t }}</div>

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but this works for our case since we only have one payment method.